# Spring Security CORS not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have the following config, based on the example here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors();
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

But when I test this out I am still able to access it from my localhost no problem. It's like the cors isn't being activated at all.

edit: I should add that I am using Spring OAuth2 and this config is located in my `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`

Comment: This doesn't change anything for me. If anything wouldn't that just allow any origin? I am trying to test not being allowed.

Comment: @dur Firefox and postman using `localhost:8080/`

Comment: Maybe you need add @CrossOrigin to your controller

Comment: I think maybe the issue is that since I am using Spring OAuth2 that it is ignoring the cors configuration on the web mvc level. Even Though I am declaring `cors()` inside my `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` I'm not sure that it is picking up on it

Comment: @zero01alpha *But when I test this out I am still able to access it from my localhost no problem.* Did your request contain the `origin` header? Firefox should it automatically, if your page is loaded from another server. Use the dev tool in Firefox to check the request headers.

Comment: @dur thanks for the tip. I am actually using Postman to call my application as this is a rest api. I will look into this origin header

Answer (score 0):

Have you annotated your class with @component? That is the class where you are initializing the CORS filter?